# jquery lightbox select source/link based on content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement, lightbox

I'm trying to create a lightbox that uses the rel attribute and the href/src (depending on the type of content). I need an if/else statement to assign an href to a variable (contentURL) if the content's a video but assign the src instead if the content's an image.

html for video content:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/..." rel="lightbox"></a>
```

html for image content:

```
<a href="#" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/photo.jpg"></a>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("a[rel='lightbox'").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var shadow = $('#lightbox-shadow'),
        lightbox = $('#lightbox');
    shadow.fadeIn(300);
    lightbox.delay(450).fadeIn(300);
    var contentURL; //assign href or src to this variable

    //IF/ELSE STATEMENT HERE

    shadow.click(function(){
        shadow.fadeOut(300);
        lightbox.empty();
    });
});
```

Also, if you could help me understand the ajax method for loading the content, that would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML above, one way to tell whether to grab the src or href attribute would be to test if the clicked link contains an image tag. I have a sample working with this code:

```
$("a[rel='lightbox'").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var shadow = $('#lightbox-shadow'),
        lightbox = $('#lightbox'),
        $target = $(e.target).closest('a'),
        $img = $target.find('img'),
        contentURL;
    shadow.fadeIn(300);
    lightbox.delay(450).fadeIn(300);
    contentURL = ($img.length > 0) ? $img.attr('src') : $target.attr('href');
    console.log(contentURL);
});
```

You can see that working here if you open the console: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9XELr/

However, this sample will only work if your youtube links never contain images. If they might, you will need to set up some other conditional logic, maybe a class or data attribute on the link itself that is different depending on the type of content.